# Populate html template content inside modal dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to populate html template dynamically using javascript

Here is what I am using

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('price_01').innerHTML = price_01;
    document.getElementById('dimension_01').innerHTML = dimension_01;
}
```

with the global variables defined inside  tags

```
var price_01 = '$8000';
var dimension_01 = '10m';
```

This work if the tags are standalone like so:

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Price:</td>
          <td id='price_01'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dimension:</td>
          <td id='dimension_01'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, when I try to populate the content inside a modal it doesn't work:

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block';" class="w3-button w3-black">More Details</button>
  <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Price:</td>
              <td id='price_01'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Dimension:</td>
              <td id='dimension_01'></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This returns blank. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a more elegant solution than what I am doing? Thanks

Edit: sorry it's not that it doesn't work inside modal, but it doesn't work when you use it both inside and outside modal. Here is the replication on TryIt Editor:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTJIGZ6U0XCK

Comment: Is the old `#price_01` still there?

Comment: Yes, but not the one inside modal. Content outside modal works just fine

Comment: Here is a replication in tryit editor: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTJIGZ6U0XCK. Figured out how the replicate the error

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements each with `id` of `price_01` and `dimension_01`, respectively. You can only have one element with a specific `id`. You should select those elements by class name instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var price_01 = '$8000';
    var dimension_01 = '10m';
    var prices = document.getElementsByClassName("price_01");
    var dimensions = document.getElementsByClassName("dimension_01");
    window.onload = function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
     prices[i].innerHTML = price_01;
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++){
     dimensions[i].innerHTML = dimension_01;
    }
 }
  </script>
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>W3.CSS Modal</h2>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td class='price_01'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dimension:</td>
            <td class='dimension_01'></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <div class="w3-container">
          <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Price:</td>
                  <td class='price_01'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Dimension:</td>
                  <td class='dimension_01'></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            
</body>
</html>
```